# Learning a chat server. Can anyone tell me what's happening here?

Tags: python

I have been trying to to learn chat server. I don't know what this code block does.

```
def get_client_name(self, client):
    info = self.clientmap[client]
    host, name = info[0][0], info[1]
    return '@'.join((name, host))
```

Can anyone tell me in detail the function of the code?

Comment: What precisely don't you understand?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that `self.clientmap` is a `dict` mapping some sort of client identifier (impossible to tell the form of that from this snippet) into a `tuple` or `list` that holds details about that particular client that's connected to the chat server.

From the assignment that's done, it appears that `info[0][0]` represents the remote host of the client connection and `info[1]` is the "name" - presumably the login name they used when connecting to the chat server? I would further surmise that perhaps `info[0]` is most-likely a 2-tuple of `(host, port)` from which the user is connected, but that's not directly supported by the code above, but purely an educated guess based on what this sort of application is likely to store.

If my assumptions above are correct, the return value of `get_client_name()` is a string representing the client in the form `username@host`. It's impossible to speculate on whether the host is stored as a DNS name or an IP address, but unless the code goes to special effort to do a reverse resolution then I'd strongly suspect an IP address.

That's mostly supposition, but it's the best that I can manage based on the code you've given - the key part of the code to look at would be where and how the `self.clientmap` dictionary is initialised.